# Custom search bar and responsive grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I've found cool article http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/how-to-create-a-seach-bar-in-photoshop.html recently. Don't know how to handle background images inside responsive grid. How do I make such a search bar using Zurb Foundation grid? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search bar in the design could be styled completely with CSS and then you wouldn't have to use background images at all. Here are a few main points of code that would make this work:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-container">
     <input type="text" />
     <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

The text input:

```
input[type="text"] {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

the button:

```
button {
    margin-left: -10%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #117a03 0%,#287c15 100%);
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 1px #fff;
    color: #074F03;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You need to add the vendor prefixes for CSS3 properties, but this is a pretty basic starting point and should give you everything you need. Here's a fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/J6Dvz/

Comment: Well! That's helpful, thank you! but.. Imagine I want to use an amazing photoshop brush to decorate search bar, or make cool thumbnail border for the first element on a page.. You can't gain this with css.  Probably sprites are good only for fixed layouts. Any thoughts? Advanced practices?

Comment: Just don't wanna quit the way I imagine the page because there is a lack of support for such things. Want to consider options.

Comment: Theres actually a css3 border property that accepts images and colors as fallbacks http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp. You could specify only the first element on the page in css too with a selector like .container + *, if it was really any element that you wanted. If you knew the specific type of element that would be better to avoid the univsersal selector. Point is, there's so much potential with CSS that its likely you could avoid using a straight photo shop image.

Comment: However if you insist, you could do something like the sliding door method: http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors. Kind of frowned upon in the web design community now as outdated, but would work perfectly for a responsive background gradient here, then just position the input and button elements accordingly